# How to move multiple rows based on criteria in merged cell?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am trying to create a project log. The projects are displayed horizontally.

In sheet "Open_Orders"

Column A is empty

Column B is Project Information Titles (Customer Name, PO Number, Start Date,  etc.) Each project has a total of 7 rows before the next project is listed
Column C are the answers to Column C (also 7 rows before the next project starts)
Column D-L is manufacturing process (Design, Approval, Parts Procurement, etc.) Each column is a merged cell that is the equivalent of 7 rows high. This will be filled in with a "p" for in progress and will fill in yellow via rule, or be filled in with "c" and will fill in green via rule.

**L is the most important column "Completion" when the cell for each project is filled with "c" when you click the refresh button, I want that whole row (Essentially 7 rows), to move to another sheet called "2019_Completed_Orders" and deletes it from "Open_Orders"

My current code moves the row when L is marked with "c", but only takes the top  row from the 7 rows. IE it takes 'Customer Name' but leaves the rest.

Also, the rows in "2019_Completed_Orders" do not follow one by one, they save over each other.

```
Sub Completed()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long
    Dim K As Long
    I = Worksheets("Open_Orders").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    J = Worksheets("2019_Completed_Orders").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If J = 1 Then
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("2019_Completed_Orders").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Open_Orders").Range("L1:L" & I)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For K = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "c" Then
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("2019_Completed_Orders").Range("A" & J + 1)
            xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
            If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "c" Then
                K = K - 1
            End If
            J = J + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. It would be easier to understand if you can provide a screen shot of your sheet

Comment: Just added it. Thanks!